# How to get rid off older chromedriver version

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was using chromedriver ver. 75.0.3770.8 however Chrome browser was updated by then and now I need to install chromedriver a least 77.0. I did so, I exchange chromedriver.exe file in the folder where the previous but it didn't work, Still there was error code 199 -> that available verison of chromedriver is 75. Then I used *webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 77.0.3865.40* and wbedriver-status command says that I have twoe versions of chromedriver:
*I/status - chromedriver versions available: 76.0.3809.12, 77.0.3865.40 [last]*
But when I attempt to run test it only seems to see 75 verison and error 199 still occurs. I've added Path Env. Variable as on this video:
https://youtu.be/dz59GsdvUF8?t=51

Any ideas how to remove the older verison 75?

Comment: Try with WebDriverManager - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protractor can be download/setup as global and local as per your npm command.
Check if your deleting from local and script pointing to global npm package of protractor or vice versa